# Using Angular and Javascript to flip a div and show different content

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs

I have this code that is in a div. Within the div, there is code to list the trips entered and code to enter the individual trips. I want to use angular to only display the form to enter each trip so when the submit button is clicked, the div will spin around and show the content that was just submitted on the other side of the div. Is There a way to do that the way I have this set up?

```
<div id="modal">
    <main ng-controller="TripsController as trips" id="temp-overflow">
      <!-- List of All the Users Trips -->
      <h2>All of your trips</h2>
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="trip in trips.current_user_trips">
          Title: {{trip.title}}
          Destination: {{trip.destination}}
          Description: {{trip.description}}
          Start Date: {{trip.start_date}}
        <div ng-controller="CommentsController as commentsCtrl">
          <h3>Comments:</h3>
            <ul>
              <li ng-repeat="comment in trip.comments">
                Entry: {{comment.entry}}
                Author: {{comment.commenter}}
              </li>
            </ul>
            <form ng-submit="commentsCtrl.createComment()">
              <input type="text" ng-model="commentsCtrl.newCommentEntry" placeholder="entry"/>
              <input type="submit" value="Comment"/>
            </form>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <!-- Form to Enter Users Latest Trip -->
      <h2>Where have you been?</h2>
      <form ng-submit="trips.createTrip()">
        <input type="text" ng-model="trips.newTripTitle" placeholder="Title"/>
        <input class="search" places-auto-complete types="['geocode']" on-place-changed="placeChanged()"/>
        <input type="text" ng-model="trips.newTripDescription" placeholder="Description"/>
        <input type="date" ng-model="trips.newTripStartDate" placeholder="Start Date"/>
        <input type="date" ng-model="trips.newTripEndDate" placeholder="End Date"/>
        <input type="text" ng-model="trips.newTripNotes" placeholder="Notes"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit your Trip"/>
      </form>
    </main>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you ask for achieve an animation with angular ? Or to display/hide elements on condition ?

Comment: This involve lot of javascript. you better use some plugin like this https://nnattawat.github.io/flip/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for the ng-show and ng-hide attributes. You can set a Boolean in your Controller to show or hide certain components of the DOM.

Here is a link to the documentation:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow

Hope this points you in the right direction.